# how to insert a checkbox in a word document

Tags: checkbox, ms-word

I want to make a list with checkbox on the left in the Word document. I don't want to use VBA macro every time.

example:

[] item1

[] item2

*[] is checkbox

Comment: show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Click the Developer tab and in the Controls group, click the Check Box Content Control, and then click to the right of the box.

-

This is the original link. There is too much redundant info.
[office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-a-checklist-in-Word-dd04fa4f-2ca7-4543-8818-c469eca9f45c)